# Operator camera_to_view_selected() doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, scripting, 3d-view, camera

**Gist:**
Why `bpy.ops.view3d.camera_to_view_selected()` doesn't work from a Class method or even a global function, when it's called from any regular method within a registered Class?

**My scenario:**
I have a scene with multiple cameras "binded" to different Markers (in the Timeline) at different frame intervals. I am trying to re-align all the active cameras at their respective frame to a selected object. For example, lets the selected object be our default Cube here.

[image: mutli-cam setup]

```
def cam_realign():
        for i in range(1, 9):
            bpy.context.scene.frame_set(i)
            bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
            active_obj = bpy.context.scene.objects['Cube']
            active_obj.select = True
            bpy.context.scene.objects.active = active_obj
            bpy.ops.view3d.camera_to_view_selected()

cam_realign()
```

The above code snippet works absolutely fine if I use as it is, i.e. just as a normal function. However, if I try to execute those very set of instructions from within a Class method it doesn't realign all the cameras except one.

```
class CamRePosition(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.cam_reposition"
    bl_label = "Repositioning of Cameras"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        for i in range(1, 9):
            bpy.context.scene.frame_set(i)
            bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
            active_obj = bpy.context.scene.objects['Cube']
            active_obj.select = True
            bpy.context.scene.objects.active = active_obj
            bpy.ops.view3d.camera_to_view_selected()

        return {'FINISHED'}
```

Any idea where I could fix this?

---

**Edit:** I did check in the console that the camera is being updated as it iterates through different frame *(as also suggested by batFINGER)*.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a test file?  As you are not changing the active object would suggest selecting cube (making it context object) and then run the operator.  Printing `print(context.scene.camera)` to console to check it is being updated (via binding)  in script.   I wonder too whether a frame change handler would be an easier option.

Comment: Sure, here is the test file: [link] (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xFX6XO_U7K_G3OUW2c_WCBjEIggHMPhQ)

Comment: @batFINGER How would you make use of a frame change handler for a workaround in this scenario?